# programmatically loading object from subclass of NSView from nib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How do I correctly load an object that is a subclass of NSView using a Xib?

I want it to be loaded dynamically not from the beginning so I made a MyView.Xib
From MyDocument.m I did:

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:myView];
[someview addSubview:myView];
...
```

and the background is fine (it calls drawrect: and it's drawn as expected)
but all the buttons I put on the xib won't appear.
I have checked, and they are loaded BUT their superview is not the same object as `myView`.

Why is this? I think I am missing something in the Xib but I don't know exactly what.
In other words: How do I make sure that the root view in my xib is the same object as file's owner?

I wish there was something similar to this for the mac:

```
NSArray* nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil]; //in iOS this will load the xib
MyView* myView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex:1];
[someview addSubview:myView];
...
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I think I have realised the origin of the problem...(??)

In MyView class I have various IBOutlet which are connected correctly in IB that is why they load just fine (I can refer them). However there is no IBOutlet for the top view. So when NSBundle loads the nib, the top view gets assigned to some other object. I thought this will happen if I set my top view in IB to be from class:`MyView` and put `myView` as the owner in `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:myView];` but it seems not to be the case.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving them  to front maybe it draws it in the back and can't be seen beacause of the background

Comment: I just tried... that is not happening ;(

Comment: In your nib file, is there a top-level view whose class is `MyView`?  Are there other top-level objects in the nib file? And what’s the class of the file’s owner?

Comment: In my nib: File's Owner class is `MyView` the top view in it is currently of class `NSView` but I have tried also `MyView`. Neither worked

Answer (score 35):

Note that a nib file contains:

- One or more top-level objects. For example, an instance of `MyView`;
- A file’s owner placeholder. This is an object that exists prior to the nib file being loaded. Since it exists before the nib file is loaded, it cannot be the same as the view in the nib file.

## Scenario 1: `NSNib`

Let’s consider that your nib file has only one top-level object whose class is `MyView`, and the file’s owner class is `MyAppDelegate`. In that case, considering that the nib file is loaded in an instance method of `MyAppDelegate`:

```
NSNib *nib = [[[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
NSArray *topLevelObjects;
if (! [nib instantiateWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects]) // error

MyView *myView = nil;
for (id topLevelObject in topLevelObjects) {
    if ([topLevelObject isKindOfClass:[MyView class]) {
        myView = topLevelObject;
        break;
    }
}

// At this point myView is either nil or points to an instance
// of MyView that is owned by this code
```

It looks like the first argument of `-[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:]` can be `nil` so you wouldn’t have to specify an owner since it seems that you aren’t interested in having one:

```
if (! [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects]) // error
```

Although this works, I wouldn’t rely on it since it’s not documented.

Note that you have ownership of the top level objects, hence you are responsible for releasing them when they’re no longer needed.

## Scenario 2: `NSViewController`

Cocoa provides `NSViewController` to manage views; usually, views loaded from a nib file. You should create a subclass of `NSViewController` containing whichever outlets are needed. When editing the nib file, set the `view` outlet and whichever other outlets you may have defined. You should also set the nib file’s owner so that its class is this subclass of `NSViewController`. Then:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
```

`NSViewController` automatically loads the nib file and sets the corresponding outlets when you send it `-view`. Alternatively, you can force it to load the nib file by sending it `-loadView`.

Comment: My nib has only one top-level object whose class is "MyView" but the file owner is "MyView" as well, is that possible?.

Comment: It is possible if you have another instance of `MyView` that has been created before the nib file is loaded. Note that this implies that this other instance has either been created programatically or loaded from another nib file, different from MyView.nib.

Comment: I have MyView *myView instance which has been created using [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:]; I am using that in [NSBundle loadNib:@"MyView" owner:myView]; I still don't get it why this is not working ;(

Comment: @nacho4d Sure, but it won’t be the same as the one loaded from the nib file. It’ll be a different view, which is why you’re facing the problems described in your question. As I wrote in my answer, ‘Since it (the file’s owner) exists before the nib file is loaded, it cannot be the same as the view in the nib file.’

Comment: @nacho4d If you think in terms of iOS, usually the owner of a nib file is some subclass of `UIViewController`, and not a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: @nacho4d Could you explain why you want the file’s owner to be an instance of `MyView`?

Comment: Yes, a subclass of UIViewController is often used but sometimes I make it a subclass of UIView because I can load that particular UIView when is need it not exactly when the view controller is loaded. (Because it is usually something that is not always visible, or something expensive to load from the beginning)  I would like to make the same thing in this mac app I am trying to do.

Comment: @nacho4d I really don’t know what else I can tell you. The file’s owner **cannot** be the same object as the top-level object of a nib file, both on Mac OS X and iOS. Look at the iOS example you wrote in your question: the owner is `self` (it’s not clear what’s the class of `self`, and it was created before the nib file was loaded) and the top-level object is `myView` — they’re **different** objects. Even if you specify the same class, the instances are not the same.

Comment: @nacho4d In your iOS example, what is usually the class of `self`?

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to this category

https://github.com/peterpaulis/NSView-NibLoading-/tree/master

```
+ (NSView *)loadWithNibNamed:(NSString *)nibNamed owner:(id)owner class:(Class)loadClass {

    NSNib * nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:nibNamed bundle:nil];

    NSArray * objects;
    if (![nib instantiateWithOwner:owner topLevelObjects:&objects]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't load nib named %@", nibNamed);
        return nil;
    }

    for (id object in objects) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:loadClass]) {
            return object;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by @Bavarious very useful, but it still needed some squirrelling on my part to make it work for my use case - load one of several xib's view definitions into an existing "container" view. Here's my workflow:

1) In the .xib, create the view in IB as expected.

2) DO NOT add an object for the new view's viewController, but rather

3) Set the .xib's File's Owner to new view's viewController

4) Connect any outlets & actions to File's Owner, and, specifically, `.view`

5) Call loadInspector (see below).

```
enum InspectorType {
    case None, ItemEditor, HTMLEditor

    var vc: NSViewController? {
        switch self {
        case .ItemEditor:
            return ItemEditorViewController(nibName: "ItemEditor", bundle: nil)
        case .HTMLEditor:
            return HTMLEditorViewController(nibName: "HTMLEditor", bundle: nil)
        case .None:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class InspectorContainerView: NSView {

    func loadInspector(inspector: InspectorType) -> NSViewController? {
        self.subviews = [] // Get rid of existing subviews.
        if let vc = inspector.vc {
            vc.loadView()
            self.addSubview(vc.view)
            return vc
        }
        Swift.print("VC NOT loaded from \(inspector)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to write the NSView subclass so the view itself comes fully from a separate xib and has everything set up correctly. It relies on the fact that `init` can change the value of `self`.

Create a new 'view' xib using Xcode. Set the File Owner's class to NSViewController, and set its `view` outlet to your target view. Set the class of the target view to your NSView subclass. Layout your view, connect outlets etc.

Now, in your NSView subclass, implement the designated initializers:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    NSViewController *viewController = [[NSViewController alloc] init];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TheNib" owner:viewController topLevelObjects:NULL];

    id viewFromXib = viewController.view;
    viewFromXib.frame = frameRect;
    self = viewFromXib;
    return self;
}
```

And the same with `initWithCoder:` so that it will also work when using your NSView subclass in an another xib.

Answer (score -1):

```
class CustomView: NSView {

@IBOutlet weak var view: NSView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)!

    let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: classForCoder)
    assert(frameworkBundle.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil))
    addSubview(view)
}
```

}