# Load view from xib in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, view, xib

I'm trying to load a view from a xib file in my cocoa application (I use storyboards).

So, I have *FirstView.xib* and some custom view in storyboard's ViewController named "*_contentView*". I do the following:

```
NSArray *nibObjects;
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstView" owner:self topLevelObjects:&nibObjects];
[_contentView addSubview: nibObjects[1]];
```

..and it works, but sometimes I get the following error:

```
-[NSApplication window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xXXXXXXXXXXXX
Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): -[NSApplication window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

What am I doing wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Search for the view, don't assume the view is `nibObjects[1]`.

Comment: But how can I search for the view?

Comment: Enumerate `nibObjects` and check the class.

Comment: Thanks, understood! I had to check nibObjects[0] and nibObjects[1] for belonging to NSView

Answer (score 1):

Don't look at the nibObjects array. That array is only there to hold on to all top-level objects in the nib. I.e. So you can just release it to have all of them go away.

Instead, define an outlet in your class (the class of the object you pass as the owner) and connect it to the desired view. Then you can just load the nib and use the view in the outlet. That is what outlets are for.

**Update:** If you have a whole list or want to otherwise load several copies of the same XIB, create e.g. a separate MYListItemViewController for each XIB, and have *that* do the loading, then have your current controller just create MYListItemViewControllers and keep an array of those, instead of directly loading them.

That's how XIBs were designed to work. It's not a good idea to load several XIBs on the same owner, You'll get multiple awakeFromNib messages, for one, and nobody expects it, so someone might add an outlet and then it gets overwritten with each load.

Comment: In some cases several views are used with several owners.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. You create an owner class that owns these views and has outlets to them. You create an instance of this owner, then have your current controller keep an array of such owners and talk to those instead of directly messing. That's how XIBs were designed to work. It's not a good idea to load several XIBs on the same owner, You'll get multiple awakeFromNib messages, for one, and nobody expects it, so someone might add an outlet and then it gets overwritten with each load.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: create a nib owner class for each nib (one simple accessory view), instatiate to load the nib, get the view and let ARC dealloc the owner? Don't expect `awakeFromNib` to be called only once.

Comment: Almost. You keep the owner around, and put any code that needs to directly know about objects in the nib into that owner. Other code outside this owner just gets a container view to place into something else. Just like NSViewController is. This will also make it easier to have variants of a nib, or to change the actual layout of the Nib without all the other code needing to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @Willeke. The solution is:

```
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:subViewName owner:self topLevelObjects:&nibObjects];
    if ([nibObjects[1] isKindOfClass:[NSView class]]){
        [_customView setSubviews:[NSArray array]];
        [_customView addSubview: nibObjects[1]];
    }
    else {
        [_customView setSubviews:[NSArray array]];
        [_customView addSubview: nibObjects[0]];
    }
```

Comment: How about `nibObjects[2]` and `nibObjects[3]`? Here's the answer: [programmatically loading object from subclass of NSView from nib](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5855561/4244136).

Comment: But the array is always of size 1

Comment: Or instead of NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init] we can use NSMutableArray *nibObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1]

Comment: If the size of the array is always 1, `nibObjects[1]` will crash. You don't have to instantiate the array, `loadNibNamed` will do this. Your `[[NSArray alloc] init]` will be thrown away.